# SQL - Removing duplicates, selecting most recent using HAVING clause & an NTEXT column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates, having

My query returns customer responses. A response table (rp) is joined to the customer table (ah). The query returns the results I want.

However it returns more than 1 response per customer if they have multiple active responses recorded.

So I tried to limit it by adding a HAVING clause yet I can't group with the responsefreetxt due to it being `NTEXT`.

```
SELECT 
    ah.CUSTACCOUNT,         /--- type = CHAR
    rp.RESPONSEFREETXT      /--- type = NTEXT
FROM 
    ah
INNER JOIN 
    rp ON rp.CUSTACCOUNT = ah.CUSTACCOUNT
    ...
WHERE 
    ah.ACTIVE = 1
    AND rp.ACTIVE = 1
    AND ...
GROUP BY 
    ah.CUSTACCOUNT, rp.RESPONSEFREETXT
HAVING 
    COUNT(ah.CUSTACCOUNT) = 1
ORDER BY 
    rp.date DESC
```

Results in this error:

> Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 21
> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Ideally I want to return 1 row per customer and in cases of duplicates, only return the most recent response.

How can I do so?

Thanks!

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this from SQL Server is to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ah.CUSTACCOUNT, rp.RESPONSEFREETXT,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ah.CUSTACCOUNT
                              ORDER BY rp.SOME_DATE DESC) rn
    FROM ah
    INNER JOIN rp ON rp.CUSTACCOUNT = ah.CUSTACCOUNT
    ...    
    WHERE ah.ACTIVE = 1 AND rp.ACTIVE = 1 AND ...
    -- I have removed the GROUP BY clause
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This assumes that there exist a column called `SOME_DATE` in the responses table which keeps track of the timestamp of each customer response.  Another way of writing the above query would use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ah.CUSTACCOUNT, rp.RESPONSEFREETXT
FROM ah
INNER JOIN rp ON rp.CUSTACCOUNT = ah.CUSTACCOUNT
...    
WHERE ah.ACTIVE = 1 AND rp.ACTIVE = 1 AND ...
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ah.CUSTACCOUNT
                            ORDER BY rp.SOME_DATE DESC);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, my problem is solved AND I learnt something new.
Top example you provided was best suited to my use case. Cheers.